# How to catch failed and canceled request in RxJs Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Since a while, I noticed that I had a few XHR that end with no HTTP status but with canceled or failed status.

It hapends on Chrome. On Firefox I didn't manage to have it.

My app works with Angular 4 and RxJs 5.

Is there any solution that could help me to catch "this errors". I call it "errors" but there're not really errors because if there were I could catch them easily.

In RxJs, when I use catch it doesn't trigger, neither do finally (or it does but after my subscription ends).
I also tried with forkJoin, zip or stuff like concat, flatMap or switchMap, but nothing seems to work in any case.

Comment: Are you using [innerHTML] somewhere in your view? Can u share screenshot of error and snippet of service cal?

Comment: I'm using innerHtml but not directly why http requests.
I have a whole service dedicated to xhr.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in your comment catch won't trigger as you face XSS issue while displaying those content on View page(i.e .html).I think you need to use DomSanitizer.

DomSanitizer helps preventing Cross Site Scripting Security bugs (XSS) by sanitizing values to be safe to use in the different DOM contexts([Detail description of DomSanitization](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer))

In your `component.ts` file use

`import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

```
this.yourVariable = domsanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<p>stack Overflow</p>');
```

and use `yourVariable` in view as follows
`<div [innerHtml]="yourVariable"></div>`

This won't give you error on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether a canceled request will trigger an error status but alternatively you can add a timeout to the observable chain which will fire an error at the end.

```
http.get(..).timeout(2000).catch()
```

Comment: Cancelled http requests don't trigger an error which is kinda strange indeed.